# Getting strange characters when copying to clipboard

Tags: windows-10, clipboard

Lately I've been seeing something strange when copying text to clipboard on my Windows 10 machine.

It does not happen all the time but when it does it is super annoying. I haven't been able to find any reference to this issue online at all, so I hope someone here can give me some direction.

So for example, when I copied this string today:
`https://admin.google.com/ac/settings/serviceonoff?iid=30`

I got this output when pasting:
`GATXUWWYDFFHN4SK64F6H3X6UVUCRGMR6BXJ4JAPT2MMG5QI5VRQLQNE`

As a test, I just copied this text:
`https://superuser.com/questions/ask` and it pasted correctly. Afterward I tried copy/pasting the first string again and got that same string.

Does this issue seem familiar to anyone? What can this be?

Comment: Have you tried to google that weird string? This is the [first result I got](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/msedge_issue-msedge_win10/copy-past-in-micro-soft-edge/703bef00-279f-4f71-86c2-9d8e3e14262d). It says that removing extensions from their browser (Edge) helped.

Comment: @gronostaj 1. I've had this issue in other programs like Visual Studio as well. Not just in the browser.
2. I tried an incognito page without extensions and still had this issue.

(although it is interesting that that you found that when googling the string. I didn't think of that because i thought it is some encrypted version of what I copied. I will try googling a bit.)

Comment: Do you have installed any clipboard enhancement program? Does it happen when booting in Safe Mode?

Comment: @harrymc Only the clipboard history from Windows 10.

I haven't tried Safe Mode because it doesn't always happen. It happens randomly.

Comment: Troubleshooting: Try running [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: That string, `GATXUWWYDFFHN4SK64F6H3X6UVUCRGMR6BXJ4JAPT2MMG5QI5VRQLQNE`, is a URL, pointing to a YouTube video. Had you previously copied that URL?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Who knows. How'd you get that? (and it doesn't explain the phenomenon.)

Comment: @harrymc it did find and correct files but the issue is still here.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: YouTube video identifiers are much shorter.

Comment: @DeeEss: As SFC found problems, not necessarily all the problems, I suggest doing a [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), which is the same as a major Windows upgrade, to put Windows into a known state.

Comment: @harrymc, agreed, I should not have called it a URL *per se* - but put it into a search engine and it point to the URL, a video.

Comment: Today i had it in Visual Studio: I copied ```require('express-async-errors');``` and got ```rG6yww4ZCAPWVR3uxSyhriWHirhjMJBpWN```

Comment: I had the same problem when copying anything in vscode and Brave browser duckduckgo.com results, but coping from notepad works fine

Comment: @RajeshJr. and did you find any possible cause or solution?

Comment: @DeeEss still has the same, but found a small trick, let say we copied abc(){} at first time and it makes pblm now we need to copy from the previous line of the code ie not coping the same thing again and paste it, it will work this time eg: print(); abc(){}

Comment: Ok. I got a bit smarter.
I see that all of the strings that give me the result that I pasted in the question are 56 characters long AND it happens with every single 56 character string I copy. - as is the result itself (56 characters long).
Is there any significance to the number 56?